# How to send array of objects to activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I read some example on this website and other but  still have error. 
It's not a compilation error but my application crash when I click on the button.

There is code of my MainActivity.java (only interesting part) :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    //blablabla

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.myLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutProp);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonValider);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openActivity2();
            }
        });
    }


    public void openActivity2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, text); // this one does not work
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, nbTextView);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

And code in Activity2.java

> public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
>
>     Intent intent = getIntent();
>     int nbTextView = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NUMBER, 0);
>
>     MyTextView[] text = (MyTextView[]) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TEXT);
>
>     TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVtest);
>
>     textView1.setText(""+ nbTextView);
> } }
> ```

if I comment : MyTextView[] text =(MyTextView[])intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TEXT);
the application does not crash.

Thank you all very much for your help

Comment: Can you please provide the exception or error produced in the console or log?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass views through intents. Views are part of the layout and cannot be shared between activities.

If you want to pass array with custom objects you must implement a Parcelable or Serializable class and use:

```
getIntent().getParcelableExtra("array");
```

or

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("array");
```

Parcelable class will be faster but it is harder to implement.

Another way is to use a library like Gson to parse your data to Json and pass it as a string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I made a stupid mistake . I added "implements Serializable" in the wrong class ...